# Should I keep my dogs off my lawn after overseeding?

Tags: grass, lawn-repair, overseeding, clover, fescue

I have a patchy lawn that I’m overseeding with a mix of tall fescue and micro clover. Should I keep my dogs off the lawn? If so, for how long? Should I worry about letting the grass reach a certain length rather than waiting for a specific period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should keep them off - once germinated, the seedlings then have to root properly and firmly into the soil. While that is happening, they are vulnerable to being pulled out by the roots for a few weeks, for example, when seeding a lawn from scratch, it should not be walked over normally for 3 months. You might not have to wait quite as long as that, but dogs do tend to cause damage on grassed areas anyway by scuffing it up when running around.